# How can I design the categories table where I can upload a product which will touch category, child category and grand child category fields?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I am building a ecommerce application for my university project. In my project every product  will belong to a category and child category(optional) and grand child category(optional). e.g product apple will belong to fresh-fruit which will belong to fruits & vegetables which will also belong to food category. Here food will be parent cat, fruits and vegetables will be child cat, fresh-fruit will be grand child cat. How can I implement the idea in the categories table where I can upload a product which will touch these  fields?

Answer (score 0):

a reasonable design would be like this :

```
===================================
C_ID      categories    parent_CID
===================================
```

it's enough for you to get the categories and it's child and it's grand child.
hint:if you are using Oracle you can use connect by to get these easily